# Unable to save dataframe as hive table from spark which is throwing serde exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have loaded one of my table in dataframe and trying to save it as hive table

```
var RddTableName= objHiveContext.sql("select * from tableName")
val dataframeTable = RddTableName.toDF()
dataframeTable.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("test.myTable")
```

I'm getting below exception
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field mytable from [public java.util.ArrayList org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.ColumnSet.col]

Comment: is there any field by name of "mytable" in your table? And what is the data type of this field?

Comment: Which version of spark you are using?

Comment: @Sumit: No Column named myTable , I have given in saveAsTable("test.myTable") where test is my Db name, I tried with SaveMode.Ignore and SaveMode.ErrorIfExits it is creating but creating in default db , spark version 1.4.1

Comment: While Saving in IgnoreMode it is saying table already exits but I am unable to view in hive tables list.......... 
 Saved output of task 'attempt_201601040502_0000_m_000000_0' to hdfs://hadoop1.domain.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/mytable/_temporary/0/task_201601040502_0000_m_000000

Comment: I am not very sure if Database name can be provided while working with Hive Context. There was a bug with 1.5 which was resolved in 1.6. can you try it with 1.6 and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The above exception is occurring as I was trying to overwrite which looks for existing table "myTable" here(and it is not there ), so to create a new table we have to go for saveMode.Ignore or ErrorIfExists. You can metion Database name in options by mapping its path

Answer (score 0):

first set hcontext.sql("use database")
 u cannot put database in saveAsTable